# Amazon multi-part upload using Gaufrette bundle

Tags: php, symfony, amazon-s3, gaufrette

Is there a way to use a Gaufrette file system object for multi-part uploading if we have an Amazon S3 adapter. I read something about the streamWrapper but I don't know if that's the way to go for it and if it's working with S3 adapeter or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The S3 Gaufrette adapter does not use multipart uploads (see https://github.com/KnpLabs/Gaufrette/blob/master/src/Gaufrette/Adapter/AwsS3.php#L135). However, you could possibly extend the adapter class and rewrite the `write()` to use the AWS SDK's `upload()` method (see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_upload) which would support multipart uploads.